# RAM memory increases while generating Two Axix plot using pyQtGraph

Tags: python-2.7, plot, pyqtgraph

I am trying to plot a real time data received by the server, while doing so the RAM memroy of my CPU (Windows XP OS) increases, I took the latest updates made by Luke-campagnola, from the link "http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~luke-campagnola/pyqtgraph/inp/files/312/tools/debian/"

any help or suggestion is appreciated in advance.

I am attaching the entire code here...

```
import sys
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
import collections
import random
import time
import math
import numpy as np
from pyqtgraph.ptime import time


class DynamicPlotter(QtGui.QWidget):   
    def __init__(self, parent = None):     
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent) 

        sampleinterval=0.1
        self.myvar = 0
        self.prevdt=0
        self.dt1 = 0


        app = QtGui.QApplication([])

        self.plot_param1 = []
        self.plot_param2 = []
        self.plot_param3 = []
        self.plot_param4 = []
        for g in range(0,100):
            self.plot_param1.append(g/100)
            self.plot_param2 .append((g+1)/100)
            self.plot_param3.append(g/100)
            self.plot_param4.append((g+1)/100)

        self.samplesize = 100;
        self.samples     = range(0,self.samplesize)

        for i in range(len(self.samples)):
            self.samples[i] = self.samples[i]/100.0

        self.framecount = 0;

        pg.mkQApp()
        self.pw = pg.PlotWidget()

        self.pw.show()
        self.p1 = self.pw.plotItem
        self.p2 = pg.ViewBox()
        self.p1.showAxis('right')
        self.p1.scene().addItem(self.p2)
        self.p2.setGeometry(self.p1.vb.sceneBoundingRect())
        self.p1.getAxis('right').linkToView(self.p2)
        self.p2.setXLink(self.p1)

        self.pw.setLabel('bottom', 'Time in Secs')
        self.pw.setLabel('left', 'Velocity in rpm')
        self.pw.setLabel('right', 'load in Nm')

    def update(self):

        self.p1.plot(self.samples, self.plot_param3)

        self.p2.addItem(self.p1.plot(self.samples, self.plot_param4, pen='b'))  


        self.dt1  = self.dt1+1

        self.p1.setYRange(min(self.plot_param3), max(self.plot_param3))
        self.p2.setXRange(self.dt1-1,self.dt1)
        self.p2.setYRange(min(self.plot_param4), max(self.plot_param4))

        if self.framecount == 0:    
            flushloop = self.samplesize 
        else:   
            flushloop = self.samplesize+1   

        for flush in range(1,flushloop):    

            self.samples.pop(0) 


    # below code is to prepare for next sample  
    self.framecount = self.framecount + 1   
    k=0
    for update in range(self.framecount*self.samplesize,
        self.framecount*self.samplesize+self.samplesize):
        if(0):
            self.plot_param1.append(self.framecount+(update/2))
            self.plot_param2.append(self.framecount+ (update/2))
            self.myvar=self.myvar-1
        else:
            self.myvar=self.myvar+1
            #self.plot_param2.append(self.framecount+ (update/2))
            #self.plot_param1.append(self.framecount+(update/2))


        self.samples.append(update/100.0)

if(self.dt1<100):
    self.plot_param1 =  np.cos(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 101))
    self.plot_param3 = self.plot_param1.tolist()
    self.plot_param2 =  np.sin(np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 101))
    self.plot_param4 = self.plot_param2.tolist()

if((self.dt1>=100)and (self.dt1 < 200)):
    self.plot_param1 =  np.cos(np.linspace(0, 20*np.pi, 101))
    self.plot_param3 = self.plot_param1.tolist()
    self.plot_param2 =  np.sin(np.linspace(0, 40*np.pi, 101))
    self.plot_param4 = self.plot_param2.tolist()

if((self.dt1>=200)and (self.dt1 < 300)):
    for f in range(0,100):

        self.plot_param1 =  np.cos(np.linspace(0, 20*np.pi, 101))
    self.plot_param3 = self.plot_param1.tolist()
    #self.plot_param3.append(1+f)
    self.plot_param2 =  np.cos(np.linspace(0, 20*np.pi, 101))
    #self.plot_param4.append(3+f)
    self.plot_param4 = self.plot_param2.tolist()




if(self.dt1 >= 300):
    self.plot_param1 =  np.cos(np.linspace(0, 10*np.pi, 101))
    self.plot_param3 = self.plot_param1.tolist()
    self.plot_param2 =  np.sin(np.linspace(0, 80*np.pi, 101))
    self.plot_param4 = self.plot_param2.tolist()



    for i in range (len(self.plot_param3)):

        self.plot_param3[i] = 20 * self.plot_param3[i]



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)    
    myapp = DynamicPlotter()
    for i in range(0,100):
        myapp.update()


    timer = QtCore.QTimer()         
    timer.timeout.connect(myapp.update) 
    timer.start(50)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with the code you posted:

1. `update()` adds new plot curves to the scene every time it is called, which is likely the reason for your memory usage. It will also affect performance. To fix this, you can call `self.p1.clear()` at the beginning of `update()`
2. The code attempts to create QApplication instances at least three times, which can cause crashes or hangs:

   - `DynamicPlotter.__init__` has a line `app = QtGui.QApplication([])`
   - `DynamicPlotter.__init__` has another line `pg.mkQApp()`, which does the same
   - The `__main__` block at the bottom also calls `QtGui.QApplication([])`

   Note also that QApplication() will be called once for each instance of `DynamicPlotter`. The function `pg.mkQApp()` is safe to call multiple times because it will check whether a QApplication has already been created.
3. `DynamicPlotter` is a subclass of QWidget, but is neither displayed nor used as a widget. This is a minor issue, but may cause confusion later on.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the code as per your comments, I was able to solve the memory issue.

When I went to debug the memory issue, I also observed that

```
1) File PlotItem.py function addItem() has
   self.items.append(item)
   self.dataItems.append(item)
   self.curves.append(item)

2) File ViewBox.py function addItem() has
   self.addedItems.append(item)
```

The above mentioned 4 list items keeps accumulating, they don't release the previously stored instance.

Not very sure why it's required to accumulate, I deleted the array using the below listed commands.

```
del self.items [0:len(self.items)]
del self.dataItems [0:len(self.dataItems)]
del self.curves [0:len(self.curves)]
del self.addedItems [0:len(self.addedItems)]
```

I didn't find any problem by adding the above 4 lines of command. Can you please give info about it.

Regards,
Pradeep K.

Comment: This is the best answer. Thank you sir.